# keyboard still displayed after switching tabs (Fragment)

Tags: android, keyboard

The keyboard is annoying me so much 
when I click the EditText the keyboard will be displayed that right
but when I change (Swipe) to the next tab . the pre keyboard is still displayed from that EditText

[image]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

As long as your Fragment creates a View, you can use the IBinder (window token) from that view after it has been attached. For example, you can override onActivityCreated in your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code worked with me

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```